# How can I call MySQL stored procedure in ecto(=> 0.11)?

Tags: mysql, elixir, ecto

I am looking for a way to use call stored procedure, there was no found.
Is it possible in an elixir's ecto lib?

Answer (score 7):

You can go directly through the SQL adapter API:

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(YourRepo, "stored_procedure(?, ?)", [param1, param2])
```

More info here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/#!Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html

Comment: Error occurred in in MySQL 5.x. (** (Mariaex.Error) unsupported query)

Comment: Oops, I believe you need to use CALL before calling the procedure in MySQL.